# SBT dependency management for build and test separetly

Tags: scala, build, dependency-management, regression-testing

I need to add dependency in `build.sbt` file but this will be used only when running my regression-test. Is there a way to specify library dependency for just build, test or regression-test?

For your reference my project structure as

```
MyProject
 - app
 - conf
 - logs
 - target
 - test
 - test-regression
 - build.sbt
```

And right now I have dependency defined in build file as

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( .... )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the way how you say that specs2 should be included only during tests:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(specs2 % Test)
```

According to the manual:

> (...) means that specs2 will only be on the test classpath and it isn't needed by the main sources.

It is described here: [Per-configuration dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#per-configuration-dependencies) but you will have to dig to figure out how to make it more general.

Comment: @michaJIS I did get that far now I am wondering can I say include only during test in test-regression folder?